# Rails how to create data schema seed data

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby

Is there a way to auto generate a seed data file and create seed data like what you would see in Laravel in below link?

[Laravel Database Migrations & Seed](http://laravel.com/docs/migrations#database-seeding)

I've seen some timestamped files created under db folder of Rails on another app with timestamp which had seed data included.

What would be good approach to create this?

Answer (score 15):

I suggest you to use the combination of [Fabrication](http://www.fabricationgem.org) gem and [Faker](http://faker.rubyforge.org).

Fabrication allows you to write a pattern to build your objects and Faker gives you fake data like names, emails, phone numbers and so on.

This is how a fabricator looks like:

```
Fabricator(:user) do
  username { Faker::Internet.user_name }
  name { Faker::Name.first_name }
  surname { Faker::Name.last_name }
  password { "testtest" }
  password_confirmation { |attrs| attrs[:password] }
end
```

In your `db/seed.rb` you can use it like this:

```
50.times { Fabricate(:user) }
```

You will get 50 fake users with random username and "testtest" password :)

Comment: Good!, where would you put the fabricators/user_fabricator.rb ? Still under the spec dir?

Comment: you can put them on spec/fabricators if you use rspec, they should be loaded automatically

Answer (score 1):

If you're looking to create *real* seed data (for a lookup table of statuses for example) you can add something like the following to your `db\seeds.rb` file.

```
# Statuses
# Will insert 5 rows in statuses table
['Not Started', 'In Progress', 'On Hold', 'Complete', 'Not Applicable'].each do |status|
Status.find_or_create_by(status: status)
end
```

Then, from your console:
 `$ rake db:seed`

To create the data when running tests you can use:
`load "#{Rails.root}/db/seeds.rb"`

Answer (score 0):

Theres a fairly useful gem for seed data called [Faker](http://rubygems.org/gems/faker). It's somewhat limited in the type of random data it generates, but I find it quite useful for simple things such as names, addresses, etc.

Of course you have to put it in a loop and write the query to insert it into the DB yourself.