# How to use Fabricate-gem to generate objects?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby-on-rails-4.2, faker, fabrication-gem

I'm using Rails 4, [Fabricate](https://www.fabricationgem.org/#defining-fabricators) and [Faker](https://github.com/stympy/faker#fakernumber) Gems. And I'm trying to seed my database with (100 or so) **randomly** created objects (Order that contains up to 3 Ice Creams). I followed [This Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/18813924/rails-how-to-create-data-schema-seed-data) that recommend using this approach.

**models/order.rb**

```
  class Order < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :ice_creams
    ...
  end
```

**models/ice_cream.rb**

```
  class IceCream < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_and_belongs_to_many :flavors
    has_many :added_extras
    has_many :extras, :through => :added_extras
    belongs_to :order
    ...
  end
```

**models/extra.rb**

```
  class Extra < ActiveRecord::Base
    ...
    has_many :added_extras
    has_many :extras, :through => :added_extras
    ...
  end
```

**test/fabricators/order_fabricator.rb**

```
  Fabricator(:order) do

    user { User.offset(rand(User.count)).first } #fine
    shift { Shift.offset(rand(Shift.count)).first } #fine
    created_at { Faker::Date.backward(365) } #fine
    ice_creams(rand: 3) { |attrs| Fabricate( :ice_cream, created_at: attrs[:created_at] ) } #fine

    total { Faker::Number.between(5, 25) }
    #add more logic depending of the total number of randomly created ice creams

    discount { [0, 10, 15, 25].sample } #fine
    total_after_discount { |order| order[:total] -  ( (order[:total] * order[:discount]) / 100 ) }
    paid { [50, 100, 200].sample } #fine
    remaining { |order| order[:paid] -  order[:total_after_discount] } #fine

  end
```

**test/fabricators/ice_cream_fabricator.rb**

```
  Fabricator(:ice_cream) do

    size { Size.offset(rand(Size.count)).first } #fine
    basis { Basis.offset(rand(Basis.count)).first } #fine
    sauce { Sauce.offset(rand(Sauce.count)).first } #fine
    topping { Topping.offset(rand(Topping.count)).first } #fine

    flavors { [ Flavor.offset(rand(Flavor.count)).first ] }
    #add additional ability to be one or two flavors randomly

    extras { [ Extra.offset(rand(Extra.count)).first ] }

    ice_cream_price { [15, 17, 18, 19, 20, 22].sample } #add logic
    extras_price { [5, 10, 15, 20 ].sample } #add logic 

    total_price { |attrs| attrs[:ice_cream_price] + attrs[:extras_price] } #fine
    created_at { Faker::Date.backward(365) }

  end
```

It's working fine , I can now create fake **Orders** that contains upto 3 fake **Ice Creams**, But the thing is I'm struglling to figure out the logic to Fabricate more realistic **Orders**, As you may noticed in my fabricators code there are some attributes that I labeled fine -Which I'm fine with it's result- and some that I still not completely satisfied of, Like...

- I wish that the Fabricated **Ice Cream** can -randomly- have one or two flavors.
- I wish to do the same thing with Extras
- I want to have the sum of the randomly Fabricated **Ice Creams** `:total_price` to be passed to the **Order** as `:total`

I've Tried to do so by creating a **Flavor** Fabricator but It didn't work..

**test/fabricators/flavor_fabricator.rb**

```
  Fabricator(:flavor) do
    Flavor.offset(rand(Flavor.count)).first
  end
```

I also tried to sum the `:total_price` the activeRecord way, but it also didn't work

**test/fabricators/order_fabricator.rb**

```
  Fabricator(:order) do
    ...
    total { self.ice_creams.sum(:total_price) }
    ...
  end
```

**So my question is...
- Are the things that I wish for possible or it's just too much? And if so how to achieve that?**

I hope I made myself clear, And you can help me,. Thanks

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It looks like you're trying to use fabrication to set calculated values on your models, `IceCream#total_price` for example. You should be letting methods on your model do their thing, like calculate that total from the parts, instead of trying to force them with fabrication.

To answer your questions specifically:

1) I wish that the Fabricated Ice Cream can -randomly- have one or two flavors.

```
Fabricator(:ice_cream) do
  flavors { Flavor.all.sample(rand(1..2)) }
end
```

2) Same as #1

3) You should have a method on `Order` that calculates the total when it is created.

Comment: Thanks, this is very helpful, Actually it worked great for the points 1 and 2. But would you explain more how to implement point 3, Actually I'm a bit newbie you know. I under stand the concept but I don't know how to put it to work.

Comment: Oh, cool. So for number 3 you'll probably want a `before_create` hook in the model that performs that calculation and saves it.

```
before_create do
  self.total ||= ice_creams.sum(:total_price)
end
```

Comment: Not sure why it would say that for `*` in that method. It's kind of tough to talk about code in these comments though. I'd be happy to have a more in-depth conversation about it in GitHub. If you want you can open an issue against fabrication and we can work through it there.

Comment: Okay but first please edit your answer and add your suggestion in it's proper context, Maybe I'm missing something.

Comment: Conversation continued on GitHub: https://github.com/paulelliott/fabrication/issues/282